# Java swing date chooser

Tags: java, swing

I am from Africa, Ethiopia. In my country every months are 30 days. After 12 month we count 5 days. But the Java JDateChooser recognize only Gregorian calendars. So how can I make it every months 30 days?

Comment: Can you use [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) (OpenJFX), the successor to Swing? Its [`DatePicker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html) class is documented as working with various *java.time* chronologies. And the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library offers chronologies including [`EthiopicChronology`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/chrono/EthiopicChronology.html) and `CopticChronology`.

Comment: Here's [another JCalendar](https://github.com/ggleblanc2/another-jcalendar) that uses the Gregorian calendar.  The source code is included in the project, so you can modify the code to use an Ethiopian calendar.

Comment: I did some research, looks like it's hard to achieve.
In Jdatechooser the setCalendar method only takes a java.util.Calendar as input. Like comments above mentioned there are other libraries that supports Ethiopic calendar system but we can not use them here.

Comment: Nice calendar system, much easier than ours. I haven’t heard about it before, and I am afraid that Java hasn’t either. :-(

Comment: Just another one https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker is using JSR-310, so at least you can use https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/, but extra work is needed ...

Comment: FYI, Swing is in maintenance mode. JavaFX is the official successor to Swing, and is actively developed. Your calendar problem is one of many reasons to move on from Swing.